# escaping string so that it can be safely used in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a javascript templating engine that generates html, all runs in browser. It is lodash.

The template looks like this (only relevant part):

```
       <button  onclick="somemethod('<%pruefobjekt.Name%>')" 
        </button>
```

The problem: If *pruefobjekt.Name* has a ' in its value, then the generated javascript is invalid. I tried *encodeURI*, but this will not replace '.

Is there a javascript function for that? Or a lodash function? I know that i can simply replace ' with some symbol and then replace it back, but this is a last resort solution.

The question with other words: Is there a javascript function that escapes strings so it can be used in javascript.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Much better to just assign the handler properly using Javascript instead of using an inline attribute (which is as bad as `eval`)

Comment: Better to trim/truncate single quote on server side instead of client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thing like below works for you ? if you are okay to use Regex.

```
function escapeString( str ) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}
```

or else Javascript has inbuilt method called stringify.

```
JSON.stringify('String with "quotes"')
```

results

```
 "String with \"quotes\""
```

Hope this helps